# Ensuring a heterogenous list contains one typeclass

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, type-level-computation

I've written my own heterogeneous list implementation (I first read about heterogeneous lists [here](http://www.parsonsmatt.org/2017/04/26/basic_type_level_programming_in_haskell.html) and my implementation is very similar to theirs)

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, TypeOperators #-}

data HList a where
  (:>) :: a -> HList b -> HList (a ': b)
  Nil  :: HList '[]
infixr 6 :>
```

This is great; however, once I found myself working with these heterogeneous lists, I found myself frequently wanting to express the idea of one where every type belongs to a particular type class.  My naïve first solution here is to rewrite the `HList` datatype entirely for each new type class.  Here's it for `Eq` (just for example; it is not the only type class I am concerned with):

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, TypeOperators #-}

data EqHList a where
  (:>) :: (Eq a) => a -> EqHList b -> EqHList (a ': b)
  Nil :: EqHList '[]
infixr 6 :>
```

This has a whole slew of problems.  For one, I need to rewrite it each time I want a new type class. Also, functions that work on my old heterogeneous lists don't work on the new ones.

My next solution was to use empty type classes.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, TypeOperators, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts #-}

data HList a where
  (:>) :: a -> HList b -> HList (a ': b)
  Nil :: HList '[]
infixr 6 :>

class Eqed a

instance Eqed (HList '[])
instance (Eq a, Eqed (HList b)) => Eqed (HList (a ': b))
```

Here an instance of `Eqed` is an `HList` of which all its elements are instances of `Eq`.  This is certainly nicer than the last solution, however I still feel it lacks.  I still have copy paste a bunch of code each time I want to talk about a different type class.  I feel like this is the type of problem that could be solved with some more type level programming.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can generalize `Eqed` by parameterizing it (requires a few extensions, GHC's error messages will tell):

```
import Data.Kind (Constraint)

class CMap (c :: * -> Constraint) (xs :: [*])
instance CMap c '[]
instance (c x, CMap c xs) => CMap c (x ': xs)
```

However this doesn't quite behave nicely, because `CMap c (x ': xs)` doesn't imply `c x`, it's only the other way around. One way may be to add a method that can use those individual constraints but that seems hairy. Another is to use a type family:

```
type family CMap (c :: * -> Constraint) (xs :: [*]) :: Constraint where
  CMap c '[] = ()
  CMap c (x ': xs) = (c x, CMap c xs)
```

Comment: If type classes are logical predicates, `CMap c xs` is a proof that all elements of `xs` satisfy `c`. For that reason I've previously seen it called `All`

Answer (score 4):

You could use `ConstraintKinds` to make the constraint a parameter of the `HList`:

```
data HList c a where
  (:>) :: (c a) => a -> HList c b -> HList c (a ': b)
  Nil :: HList c '[]

exampleList :: HList Eq '[Int, String, Double]
exampleList
  = (1 :: Int)
  :> ("two" :: String)
  :> (3.0 :: Double)
  :> Nil
```

Or use `ExistentialTypes`/`GADTs` and a regular list, if you only need the typeclass and don’t mind losing the static type information about which concrete types are in the list:

```
data SomeEq = forall a. Eq a => SomeEq a

data SomeEq where
  SomeEq :: Eq a => a -> SomeEq

exampleList :: [SomeEq]
exampleList =
  [ SomeEq (1 :: Int)
  , SomeEq ("two" :: String)
  , SomeEq (3.0 :: Double)
  ]
```

However, this isn’t terribly useful in the case of `Eq`, unless you also propagate information about type equalities so that you have something useful to which you want to compare the abstract wrapped value. As it is, the only thing you can do with this is compare a wrapped value to itself.

There may be better/simpler options depending on your particular application.